# Adding Some Pizzaz to a UISegmentedControl and UITableView Combination

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a basic app with a `UISegmentControl` in the header and a `UITableView` that can toggle between four different overlapping categories. Does an easy way exist to add some fancy animations (cells dropping and being added) when a user switches between categories? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of animation you want. But there are some default but beautiful animations available. Use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` to insert the rows. You can use any one of the following animations with this method.

```
 UITableViewRowAnimationFade
 UITableViewRowAnimationRight
 UITableViewRowAnimationLeft
 UITableViewRowAnimationTop
 UITableViewRowAnimationBottom
 UITableViewRowAnimationNone
 UITableViewRowAnimationMiddle
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was looking for an automatic way to perform this on multiple data sets given the current visible data set (i.e. multiple `NSFetchedResultsController` or multiple `NSArray`).